# Limits to infinity of a factorial function: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!}{n^{n/2}}$

Tags: limits, exponentiation, factorial, radicals, infinity

How can this limit to infinity be solved? I've tried with d'Alembert but it just keeps coming up with the wrong answer.

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!}{n^{n/2}}$$

I might have a problem in simplifying factorial numbers. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 10):

Hint:
use  Stirling's approximation:
$$n!\sim {\sqrt {2\pi n}}\left({\frac {n}{e}}\right)^{n}.$$

Comment: Is this the only way to solve this?Can you please provide some alternative way may be using inequalities etc.

Comment: I think this is the easiest way

Comment: It's easy if you know it. If you don't, it's not a way at all.

Comment: Exactly,I second that @zhw.;I don't know this formula at all

Answer (score 9):

**HINT:**

Without appealing to Stirling's Formula, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\frac{(2n)!}{(2n)^{n}}&=\frac{2n(2n-1)(2n-2)\cdots (2n-(n-1))\cdot  n(n-1)\cdots 3\cdot2\cdot1}{\underbrace{(2n)\cdots (2n)}_{n\,\,\text{copies}}}\\\\
&=\left(1/2+\frac{1}{2n}\right)\left(1/2+\frac{2}{2n}\right)\cdots \left(1/2+\frac{n-1}{2n}\right)\,n!\\\\
&\ge \frac{n!}{2^n}
\end{align}$$

So, the problem boils down to showing that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n!}{2^n}=\infty$.

Comment: Aren't there some problems? 1. In the Numerator will not it be $2n-(n-1)$?2.In the second step will not it be $\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2n}$?

Comment: @learnmore I suggest you have a closer look.  The bound is not only correct, it is rather crude.  Find an $n$ for which it is invalid and revert.

Comment: @learnmore $2n-(n-1) =n+1$, whereupon dividing by $2n$ yields $1/2+1/(2n)$.  So what on earth is the issue?

Comment: Sorry,I am still having an issue;In the first line should not it be $2n(2n-1)(2n-2)\cdots (2n-(n-1)).n(n-1)\cdots 3.2.1$

Comment: @learnmore Ah, yes,  a typo.  Great catch!  I've edited accordingly.  Much appreciative. -Mark

Comment: In the next line ,I think you are dividing $2n(2n-1)(2n-2)\cdots (2n-(n-1))$ by $(2n)^{n}$.Will it not be $(1-\frac{1}{2n})(1-\frac{2}{2n})\cdots (1-\frac{n-1}{2n})?$

Comment: A@learnmore No.  I'm dividing by $n^n$.  The $2^n$ is left in the denominator.

Comment: Sorry ,I still don't get why u got $(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2n})$ instead of $(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2n})$?

Comment: @learnmore $2n-(n-1)=n+1$.  Now divide by $2n$.

Comment: Can you just write the in between steps in your answer if possible?Really getting tough out there for me

Answer (score 4):

**Using Stirling's Approximation**

Stirling's Asymptotic Approximation says that
$$
n!\sim\sqrt{2\pi n}\,\frac{n^n}{e^n}\tag{1}
$$
This means that the expression in the question is
$$
\frac{n!}{n^{n/2}}\sim\sqrt{2\pi n}\,\,\frac{n^{n/2}}{e^n}\tag{2}
$$
which grows without bound. Therefore,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!}{n^{n/2}}=\infty\tag{3}
$$

---

**Another Approach**

Squaring and writing the factorial forward and backward, for $n\ge4$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{n!}{n^{n/2}}\right)^2
&=\overbrace{\frac{1(n-0)}{n}\frac{2(n-1)}{n}}^{\ge1}\overbrace{\frac{3(n-2)}{n}\cdots\frac{(n-2)3}{n}}^{\ge\left(\frac32\right)^{n-4}}\overbrace{\frac{(n-1)2}{n}\frac{(n-0)1}{n}}^{\ge1}\\
&\ge\left(\frac32\right)^{n-4}
\end{align}
$$
Each product in the numerator under the middle brace is $k(n-k+1)$. Since $k+(n-k+1)=n+1$ one of the numbers must be $\gt n/2$ while both are greater than $3$. Therefore, under the middle brace, $\frac{k(n-k+1)}n\gt\frac32$. For $n\ge2$, each of the terms under the outer braces is $\ge1$.

Comment: Is this the only way to solve this?Can you please provide some alternative way may be using inequalities etc.

Answer (score 4):

$$n!\geq\left (\frac{n}{4}\right )^{3n/4}\\\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\left (\frac{n}{4}\right )^{3n/4}}{n^{n/2}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^{n/4}}{4^{3n/4}}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{n}{64}\right)^{n/4}=\infty$$
The inequality comes since $4n!=1\cdots \underbrace{n\cdots 4n}_{3n}\geq \underbrace{n\cdots n}_{3n}=n^{3n}$

Comment: That's a nice approach+1

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

$$n! = \int_0^\infty t^ne^{-t}\, dt > \int_n^{2n}t^ne^{-t}\, dt > n\cdot n^n e^{-2n} \ge n^ne^{-2n}.$$

Dividing by $n^{n/2}$ gives

$$ n!/n^{n/2} > n^{n/2}e^{-2n} = \exp [(n/2)\ln n - 2n].$$

Since $(n/2)\ln n - 2n \to \infty,$ the desired limit is $\infty.$

Answer (score 0):

First note that for $n\geq 1$, we have
$$n!\geq e\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$$
$$\frac{n!}{n^{n/2}}\geq e\left(\frac{\sqrt n}{e}\right)^n$$
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!}{n^{n/2}}\geq \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}e\left(\frac{\sqrt n}{e}\right)^n=\infty$$
Therefore
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!}{n^{n/2}}=\infty$$

Comment: The fact that $n!\ge \sqrt{n^n}$ does not imply alone that the limit of the ratio is infinite.

Comment: What is the limit of (n! + 1) / n! ? The numerator is always larger than the denominator, so therefore the limit goes to infinity, right?  That's your theory here. But that's absurd; in my example the sequence never even gets larger than 3. So where is the flaw in the argument?

Comment: @Dr.MV, Thanks for the correction. Please see my edit.

Comment: @EricLippert, please see my edit and thanks for the correction.